# Validate String JWT using Apex

Tags: apex, jwt

I have generated JWT token. I added it as String argument in one method I have to call.
Is there a way to validate that String token if it is expired, valid, etc?

Comment: Out of the box - no. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I send some request, sometimes I got invalid or expired token error. I want to prevent sending request if token is expired or invalid. @identigral

Comment: Are you sending from Salesforce to an external service or inbound to Salesforce?

Comment: Yes, from Salesforce to an external API. @identigral

Comment: If you're generating a token in Apex, take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324426/generate-jwt-token-for-external-app-sso .

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does provide Apex support for JWS/JWT:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_JWS.htm

-and-

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_JWT.htm

Although unfortunately the JWS class only supports generating signatures and not verifying them. However you can verify the signature yourself:

[Using the Crypto.verify() method to verify a JWT signature](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273742/using-the-crypto-verify-method-to-verify-a-jwt-signature)

Once you've verified that the payload is valid, then you can examine any of the Claims to make sure that they are acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, but Crypto.verify asks for publicKey which I do not have. How to resolve this?