# Convert Base64 decoding from Java to Apex

Tags: base64

In Java we have this code:

```
byte[] clientPublicKeyBase = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(...);
```

How do I convert this to Apex?

Comment: From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html) for `Base64.getUrlDecoder()`: _Uses the "URL and Filename safe Base64 Alphabet" as specified in Table 2 of RFC 4648 for encoding and decoding. The encoder does not add any line feed (line separator) character. The decoder rejects data that contains characters outside the base64 alphabet_. Have you looked at Table 2 of RFC 4648 and tried implementing?

Comment: Check this Dev Forum link on similar topic https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zfhIAA

Comment: @identigral Thank you so much for the tip, 
As you said, It was necessary to encode while converting to RFC 4648
Using this info I found a previous answer of yours 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273742/using-the-crypto-verify-method-to-verify-a-jwt-signature  and it worked perfect, thank you so much